# Angularjs - ng-model undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am building a rather complex directive in which I need access to ng-model on a specific element in the template which is enclosed into ng-if directive... I have a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bQSIZE6gik36UkJkvTM0?p=preview) and the explanation on how to see the issue is below.

In the .compile function of the directive I have a line of code that looks like this

```
ngModel = elm.find('textarea').controller('ngModel');
console.log(ngModel);
```

In my template, I have a something like this:

```
<div  ng-if="views.view">
    <textarea ng-model="exp.val"></textarea>
</div>
```

When I use `ng-show` my `console.log` gets an object of `ng-model`, no problem ...

The requirement is very strict however and I have to use `ng-if`. When I use `ng-if` my console log gets **undefined**

The actual working version of the problem exists in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bQSIZE6gik36UkJkvTM0?p=preview)

**If you change the line 6 in template.html into ng-if you can see the behavior.**

How do I have to write this line to retrieve the model when inclosed in ng-if.

```
ngModel = elm.find('textarea').controller('ngModel');
```

I also tried using [attach-if](https://github.com/Sparks-Creative-Limited/angular-attach-if) directive by [Simon Sparks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2054713/simonsparks). This directive is pretty cool, it preserves the scope unlike ng-if so if you specifically need to not render HTML but you need to preserve scope it works great.

I still have the same problem with invoking ngModel as I am doing it but because of applying custom filters in the directive I have to update ng-model in this way.

*I am this one step away from finishing this directive. Hoping someone can help.*

Comment: `ng-if` stops the element from being added to the DOM— you can't retrieve it using `find()`

Comment: cwap,, you're right,, the element is not there,,, :/ .. suggestions on how to bypass this and keep the non rendering... When I don't use ngModel = elm.find... and I use attach-if ,, it works,, I need a way to apply the filter conditionally still...

Comment: What is the intended outcome... to display the `textarea` with model data?

Comment: yes,, to display textarea with model data and update the model from textarea,, BUT I have to use the markdown filter conditionally,, update the view with markdown converted html and keep the source in the model. I am using the ng-if because I can't have the element rendered (security related issue - it is a requirement)

Comment: Hey,, I found a workaround that enables me not to have to search for ngModelCOntroller,, I would still prefer doing it this way if anything crosses your mind though.. so feel free to give input if you have time to spare. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Will do. Still actually thinking about your issue. What's the solution you found?

Comment: I created a markdown filter and depending on the directive's attribute type value I use ng-if to display a different element with output that either uses the filter or not. This allows me to not have to invoke ngmodel controller manually but I can use it in a quite standard way.